# Prioritization of IF-ELSE / TRY-CATCH and First() vs Single()

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, try-catch

So, I've been having a little bit of an argument with a fellow coder lately. Specifically: We've been arguing about the proper use of `Try / Catch` and `If / Else` as well as `First() / Single()` in a specific scenario.

**Variation #1**  - His approach

```
var items = Search(dto.number); // Returns a List of Objects
if (items.Count = 1)
{
    wPerson = items.First();
}
else
{
    return;
}
```

**Variation #2** - I changed his code to this.

```
var items = Search(dto.number); // Returns a List of Objects
try
{
    wPerson = items.Single();
}
catch
{
    // Handle exception
    return;
}
```

We expect the result of `var items = Search(dto.number);` to always be 1.

**The Question:**
Which changes were nescessary? I am trying to defend my point of view below. Please correct me.

First of all: The `Single()`. I always try to be as specific as possible and I decided on the following rules:

> - First --> Accepts N
> - FirstOrDefault --> Accepts 0 and N
> - Single --> Accepts 1
> - SingleOrDefault --> Accepts 0 and 1

`First()` may have worked but it wasn't 100% specific, so I considered it wrong since we had an option to be even more specific.

Secondly: `Try / Catch` vs `If / Else`. Since I had already changed `First()` to `Single()`, I considered the `if` statement to be redundant. Yes. I know that `Try / Catch` is less performant than the `If` statement but we expect to have NOTHING BUT 1 result. And if we get more or less, I expect it to be a mistake and with `Try / Catch` I'd actually treat it that way.

Am I so off here?

Comment: Exception is for *exceptional situation* only; if you put, say, `Single` you expect one and only one item only; if you get, say, `2` or *nothing* it means that something id very wrong. if however it's *quite possible* that you can have `0`, `1` or `2` items you should use `FirstOrDefault`

Comment: @Fildor Yes that was a typo --> Sry and thx.

Comment: What is the type of `wPerson` / `vwPerson`? Is it a class or struct? How is it declared? Is it assigned prior to this code?

Comment: Why do you want to pay the cost of an exception when you have all the ways to avoid it?

Comment: Firstly, the `Single` with a generic `try catch` is definitely poor. Don't use that approach. It will cause your issues if `Search` returns `IQueryable`, for example, since at that point the `Single` may throw an exception due to database connectivity issues.

Comment: If `Search` is expected to provide a list with exactly 1 entry, then why does it return a list at all instead of a singe entity (or null)?

Comment: Have you considered using `FirstOrDefault` or `SingleOrDefault` to simplify Variant #1?

Comment: `but we expect to have NOTHING BUT 1 result.` Your logic here seems problematic to me. In my mind, you have two broad options. a) Optimistic. You know the method returns 0 or 1 entries. OK, easy - so the simplest solution is `FirstOrDefault` (without checking `Count`). b) Pessimistic. I expected only one result. I received multiple. This is catastrophic. Throw an exception up the chain (likely using `SingleOrDefault`).

Comment: Following from above, your `Variation #1` is similar to my a). But your #2 doesn't fill the bill for either a) **or** b). It _acts_ the same as a), but is slower (Single can be slower than First since it often checks the first two elements, and exception handling is expensive)  and much harder to read and grok. I'd find it hard to defend your #2.

Comment: @mjwills What you say + I'd argue all this should be `Search` Method's concern, not the client's.

Comment: @mjwills I am - So getting rid of Try / Catch. Noted. No, I have not considered FirstOrDefault or SingleOrDefault to simplify Variant #1 up until now but I see how that would make more sense.

Comment: @Fildor What if I can't change the search method? And if the correct approach is to never even return a list that we expect only 1 item in, why would .Single() even exist?

Comment: @Xaphas You can read the docs for the difference between `First` and `Single`. `First` says 'give me the first one, and there must be at least one'. `Single` says 'give me the first one, and there must be **exactly** one'.

Comment: @Xaphas If you can't change `Search` - that's understandable if you are working in legacy code (or as we say here "it has a history"). I just wanted to add the idea. There is of course always the situation, where you just cannot change the behavior of a widely used function. The existence of `Single` is untouched by good interface design. The implementation still can use it. The point is you'd usually not want to have _the client_ care if exactly 1 result is already expected from the function. Because then you'll make _all clients_ care at _every_ use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, throwing / catching *exceptions* is for *exceptional situation only*, so your current code

```
try {
  wPerson = items.Single();
}
catch {
  // Something is very wrong (e.g. RDBMS table's ruined, file's corrupted etc)

  throw;
}
```

means that you expect *one and only one* `wPerson` in `items`. If,  however, `0`, `1`, or `2` `item` in `items` is *expected behaviour*
you should not use `Single`, but, say, `Take`

```
var items = Search(dto.number); // Returns a List of Objects

var wPersons = items.Take(2).ToArray();

if (wPersons.Length <= 0) {
  // No person found; probably, wPerson = some_default_value
  ... 
}
else if (wPersons.Length == 1) {
  // Exactly one person found
  wPerson = wPersons[0];
  ...
} 
else { 
  // Two or more persons found; we have to resolve tie somehow
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't try/catch if you can avoid it. An exception should be used to "exceptional flow", iE: not to be expected.

However I'd suggest you combine both of the variations.

```
var items = Search(dto.number); // Returns a List of Objects
if (items.Count != 1) return;
wPerson = items.Single();
```

1. Since you expect only 1 result if successful, you can immediately break.
2. If, for any reason, you change your code and there are x > 1 items this method will break since you only expect 1 (hence the Single) and not go into an "unexceptional" flow (assuming the First object is the correct object)